# Quantum relative entropy and commutation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-entanglement

We know that the relative entropy of entanglement and discord are defined as
$$
  \begin{eqnarray}
    E_r(\rho) = \min_{\sigma \subset \mathcal{S}} S(\rho||\sigma) = - \mathrm{Tr} \rho \log \sigma - S(\rho) ,
\\
    D_r(\rho) = \min_{\chi \subset \mathcal{C}} S(\rho||\chi) = - \mathrm{Tr} \rho \log \chi - S(\rho) .
  \end{eqnarray}
$$
where $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of separable states and $\mathcal{C}$ is the set of classical states(which here is the set of classical-classical states). The two sets can each be expresses as the following form:
$$
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \rho &=& \sum_{ij} p_{ij} \rho_i \otimes \rho_j ,
\\
  \rho &=& \sum_{ij} p_{ij} |i \rangle \langle i| \otimes |j \rangle \langle j| .
  \end{eqnarray}
$$

If we denote the states that minimize the entropies by $\sigma_*$ and $\chi_*$ respectively, then can they be diagonalized at the same time as $\rho$, in other words do the commutations $[\rho,\sigma_*]=0$ and $[\rho,\chi_*]=0$ hold, so that the entropies can be written in eigenvalue form? It seems natural to me that the "nearest" state to $\rho$ be able to commute with $\rho$.